# no module named 'glue.lal'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've found that I need to install 'glue' first.
But after that, this error is still there.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Saisa\Desktop\Code\python\myWebSpiderForPixiv_top100.py", line 1, in <module>
    from gwpy.timeseries import TimeSeries
  File "C:\Users\Saisa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\gwpy\timeseries\__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    from .core import *
  File "C:\Users\Saisa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\gwpy\timeseries\core.py", line 45, in <module>
    from ..data import (Array2D, Series)
  File "C:\Users\Saisa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\gwpy\data\__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
    from glue.lal import (Cache, CacheEntry)
ImportError: No module named 'glue.lal'
```

Comment: How did you install it?

Comment: I use this command:pip install glue

Comment: What's the output of `pip --version`?

Answer (score 0):

Your Problem is that Python does not know where to find the module. You must add the path to the Path Browser where the module code is saved in and then you can use the

```
    import themoduleyouwant
```

Or

```
    from themoduleyouwant import *
```

command.

You can find the Path Browser under `"File >> Option >> Path Browser"`
Usually, it will show you the standard libraries and your current working directory (cwd). So if you are looking for a quick solution, just take the directory of 'glue' and copy+paste it into your cwd.

Result: The Error will disappear.

Comment: @SaisanCN Can you find the cwd in the path browser? I think there might be another problem. Since I don't know the structure of your modules it's hard for me to explain, I'll put another answer below

Answer (score 0):

Here is another idea of what you could try:

If I understand right, your directory hieracy looks something like this:

```
     \root
         \glue
             \lal
             \other
             \another
```

and in lal there are the functions and classes and whatever you want. Is lal a directory or a file? If it is a directory, I don't understand why It is not working, I just wrote a analogue code and for me it worked perfectly. Maybe  ther error is somewhere entierely else, sh*t happens in python, too. But if it is a file like `lal.py` you don't have to tell from glue.lal import (whatsoever)! This whatsoever are functions then in one file. Just type `from glue import lal`, it will import everything in there.